# Angular - Form Builder - Form Control invalid not updating / ngIf error

Tags: angular, forms, validation, reactive

I want an error division to pop up when the validator is invalid, but it does not.

Error is most likely in this line:

```
<div class = "danger" *ngIf="firstName?.invalid 
&& (firstName?.dirty || firstName?.touched)">
```

Expected behaviour: when the form is invalid the input should show an error div

Actual behaviour: no div shows however the validation does work correctly for the form over-all.

Form Builder:

```
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  detailsForm;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  ) { 
    this.detailsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      firstName: ['',[Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern("[a-zA-Z]+")]],
      lastName: ['',[Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern("[a-zA-Z\s]+")]],
      email: ['',[Validators.required,
        Validators.email]],
      region: ['',[Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern("[a-zA-Z\s]+")]],
      yearOfBirth: ['',[Validators.required, 
        Validators.pattern("^(19[0-9]{2})|(2[01][0-9]{2})$")]],
    }, { updateOn: "blur" })
  }
}
```

Template: note omitted other inputs to reduce text amount

```
<div class="center-container">
    <form [formGroup]="detailsForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <div>
            <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
            <input id="firstName" type="text" formControlName="firstName">
            <div class = "danger" *ngIf="firstName?.invalid && (firstName?.dirty || firstName?.touched)"> 
                ERROR
            </div>
        </div>
</form>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try getting the control out of the form object like this:

```
<div class="center-container">
    <form [formGroup]="detailsForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <div>
            <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
            <input id="firstName" type="text" formControlName="firstName">
            <div class = "danger" *ngIf="firstName?.invalid && (firstName?.dirty || firstName?.touched)"> 
                ERROR
            </div>
        </div>
</form>   
</div>
```

In your component.ts

```
get firstName() {
    return detailsForm.get('firstName');
}
```

Docs: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#built-in-validators

Comment: Thank you! It works. Is there any short-hand way around this?

Comment: The documentation does suggest adding a getter in the component that returns your control. I'll update the example to reflect that

Comment: Please mark as answer if you feel this will help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form [formGroup]="detailsForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <input id="firstName" type="text" formControlName="firstName">
    <div 
        class = "danger"
        *ngIf="detailsForm.get('firstName')?.invalid && 
                   (detailsForm.get('firstName)?.dirty || 
                   detailsForm.get('firstName')?.touched)"
        > 
            ERROR
    </div>
</form>
```

OR

```
<form [formGroup]="detailsForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <input id="firstName" type="text" formControlName="firstName">
    <div 
        class = "danger"
        *ngIf="detailsForm.controls.firstName?.invalid && 
                   (detailsForm.controls.firstName?.dirty || 
                   detailsForm.controls.firstName?.touched)"
        > 
            ERROR
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try like this:

```
    <form [formGroup]="detailsForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <div>
            <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
            <input id="firstName" type="text" formControlName="firstName">
            <div class = "danger" *ngIf="detailsForm.get('firstName')?.invalid && (detailsForm.get('firstName')?.dirty || detailsForm.get('firstName')?.touched)"> 
                ERROR
            </div>
        </div>
     </form>
```